# AngularJs ui-router reload template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a angularjs project that's using ui-router for routing.
I am using `$state.reload()` to reload the current state and it works just fine except that in my development system i want the `$state.reload()` to also reload the html template to reflect the new changes without a full page reload.

Is there a hack or option to do this ?

Update :

Chris T's solution almost worked, but i have `templateFactoryDecorator` witch adds a cache buster to the template url.

```
function configureTemplateFactory($provide) {
    // Set a suffix outside the decorator function
    var cacheBuster = Date.now().toString();

    function templateFactoryDecorator($delegate) {
        var fromUrl       = angular.bind($delegate, $delegate.fromUrl);
        $delegate.fromUrl = function (url, params) {
            if (url !== null && angular.isDefined(url) && angular.isString(url)) {
                url += (url.indexOf("?") === -1 ? "?" : "&");
                url += "v=" + cacheBuster;
            }

            return fromUrl(url, params);
        };

        return $delegate;
    }

    $provide.decorator('$templateFactory', ['$delegate', templateFactoryDecorator]);
}
```

so

```
$templateCache.remove($state.current.templateUrl);
```

didn't work and i had to use

```
$templateCache.removeAll();
```

Its not ideal but for development environment its ok.

Comment: try this `go` instead of `reload` . `$state.go('the state you want to go to', null, {reload: true});`

Comment: @MjZac `$state.reload()` calls `$state.transitionTo`. `$state.go` calls `$state.transitionTo` internally, so they both are doing the same thing.

Comment: What do you mean "reload the HTML template to reflect the new changes"? Are you changing the HTML in the template? Or is it just the data that is changing and the template needs to be re-rendered?

Comment: @SunilD.Yes, i am talking about a development environment where  i am changing the html template file in the server,and would prefer to reload that single html file instead of refreshing the hole page.

Comment: hi @Exlord, any progress to that? i am also stuck on the same thing.

Comment: hey @AlexRumbaNicked , no not really, I gave up.

Answer (score 5):

Internally, UI-Router [leverages the $templateCache service](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/0.2.15/src/templateFactory.js#L85-L87) to avoid re-fetching templates.  Before calling `$state.reload()`, clear out the template you want to refetch from the server.

Assuming you want to do this from a controller:

```
function MyController($scope, $templateCache, $state) {
    $scope.reload = function() {
        $templateCache.remove("/path/to/template.html");
        $state.reload();
    }   
}
```

Docs:

- [$templateCache](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/docs/api/ng/service/$templateCache)
- [$cacheFactory](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/docs/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory)

On a side note, I find it odd that you would want to refetch the template from the server.

Comment: `On a side note, I find it odd that you would want to refetch the template from the server.`  this is for a development environment only, just to make the dev easier when i make changes to the template file.

Comment: Have you looked into something like browsersync, or livereload?

Comment: that sounds nice but still need to call reload to reinitialize the controller and it won't update the template cache either.

Comment: Browsersync and livereload both refresh the browser (like hitting ctrl-r).  The whole application is re-bootstrapped, so it would indeed reset the template cache and reload the controller.

Comment: LOL the hoe reason for my question is that i wont have to reload the hole page every time there is a small change in one of the files :D

Answer (score 0):

I may have missed your point but When you use **$state.reload()** it reloads the state that means all the partials in side that template and the controllers in side that controller scope. Thus the state is reloaded not the full page.

So I see no errors in your side unless you want to do other staff ..
And if you are dynamically generating the DOM, It will do it for you .

Comment: The html template file dose not gets reloaded from the server, just the controller. The html template is read from the cache